# some confusions about " property" in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

```
@interface TheViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITableView  *table;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView  *table;
```

or just like this:

```
@interface TheViewController : UIViewController
{

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView  *table;
```

Is it ok like the second one?

And what is the difference ?

And which is recommended ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok like the second one?

The two syntaxes are correct, generally speaking.

> And what is the difference ?

The second one will also declare the `ivar` for you, but will only work correctly newer Objective C runtime systems.

> And which is recommended ?

good question... I think they are pretty equivalent, provided you can restrict yourself to the  newer ObjC runtime systems. For more hints at possible downsides of not declaring ivars explicitly, please have a look at this [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957288/why-does-a-subclass-property-with-no-corresponding-ivar-hide-superclass-ivars).

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C 2.0, synthesized properties will automatically create the corresponding ivars as required. So both syntaxes are correct..[This](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/dynamic-ivars-solving-fragile-base.html) article will make it clear for you..

Comment: so,in another word,in the second case,the Objective-C 2.0 will automatically add "IBOutlet UITableView  *table;"part for me? right?

Answer (score 1):

These two are not quite equivalent even in the ObjC 2.0 environment because of the IBOutlet. That has to be declared on the property. They'd be equivalent like this:

```
@interface TheViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITableView  *table;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView  *table;

@interface TheViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView  *table;
```

Notice the added IBOutlet in the property definition.

Comment: hmm,this is not the point.IBOutlet is what i forgot to add:),

Comment: Then in that case they are equivalent and yes the `@synthesize` will give you everything that you need. Though, as noted below (bymacbirdie) the debugger will not see the iVar.

Answer (score 0):

Generally they're equivalent in Objective-C 2.0 environment, but the debugger, for example, won't see the generated ivar as this object's member in the variables view and you'll have to ask for the value by using gdb's command line `po` command using the accessor method (not the short-form dot notation though).