# Objective-C: do you use @private visibility/access modifier in your code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

There are 3 modifiers: @private, @protected (default) and @public. Being accustomed to do so in C++ and other more sane languages, I always use @private for my fields. I barely (if ever)see that in SDK examples from Apple - they just rely on the default one.

One day I realized that Objective-C inheritance is rather fake feature: deriving an interface from another one doesn't mean all private fields are now available for redefinition. The compiler still sees them and disallows defining a new private field with the the same name, which goes orthogonal with classic encapsulation paradigm in OOD.

So I am a bit frustrated. Maybe I am expecting too much from the language because it's nothing more than a build up over standard C.

So do you use @private in your code? Why?

Comment: ...C++....sane??....doesnotcompute...

Comment: Well, compared to Objective C sanity :) I mostly use C# nowadays though.

Comment: C++ is not sane compared to Objective-C, you just haven't learned enough Objective-C yet. Objective-C is a small, small language. :)

Comment: Should I post another question? :)

Comment: Is it really a good idea for both a base class and a subclass to have individual private variables with the same name?

Comment: @dreamlax: in C++, when all private stuff is not visible to anything, including IDE, that's totally fine. IMHO, it's the same as using i as a variable in "for" loops in the same method. In Objective-C that's not possible so we can't even discuss if it's a good idea or not.

Comment: @Schultz9999: I was talking about in C++. I was asking in what kind of situations is it useful to have two private member variables with the same name? If they have the same name, why aren't they a common or more descriptively named? I'm asking because I'm new to C++ and I can't think of any situations where having two identically-named private member variables is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's a good idea to always use `@private`, but I've never bothered in the past because I generally use property accessors for almost all ivar access except in `init` and `dealloc` methods.  So in practice, I rarely have a problem of accessing ivars by mistake.

Also, if you're targeting iOS 4+, you don't need to declare ivars for properties if you use `@synthesize`.

---

I should note that if you're writing library code that is meant to be subclassed by other developers, the use of `@private` would be more important.

Comment: That's useful info - I didn't know that ivars are optional in V4+.

Comment: Yeah, since I never use object->ivar, I don't worry about making my ivars private.

Comment: Although properties no longer officially need ivars, not having them seems to result in some [odd behaviours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336922/whats-the-purpose-of-an-ivar-when-a-property-exists/3958099#3958099).

Comment: Synthesized ivars not showing up in the debugger is definitely annoying. That's with GDB -- I wonder if LDB with LLVM compiler has the same issue.  The second annoyance in that post should be moot unless you're accessing superclass ivars directly, which I think most people avoid doing.

Answer (score 2):

I do out of habit, but it really doesn't matter unless you're shipping a binary framework others will link agianst, which I'm pretty sure you're not doing.

All `@private` does is restrict the visibility of the members of the object struct (accessed like `obj->_ivar`, rather than `[obj getter]` or `obj.getter`). It's a nice sanity check since it will error if you try to do it outside the class -- pretty much the only place to use direct structure access is when implementing `NSCoding` or `NSCopying` and those will still work -- but it doesn't really buy you much.

Comment: `@private` actually restricts a bit more than the `obj->_ivar` construct.  In a subclass's method, without `@private` you can directly access ancestral ivars just like its own ivars, i.e. `_parent_ivar` instead of `self->_parent_ivar`.

Answer (score 1):

It's only really useful for Apple or folks who are shipping libraries that want to expose certain fields only to themselves in header files.  We never use it because the accessor model lets you expose (or not) what you want.  Since I have both header and source files what good is private really?  Objective-C isn't C++ so @private has a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In all the code I've written in Objective-C since 1989, I've never bothered to use @public, @protected, or  @private.